# Proguard for Android issue

Tags: android, proguard

I want to build my android project with proguard.while exporting it gives such error log.Please give me a solution.

```
 Warning: there were 28 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Comment: I'm just perplexed at why you need to state "Please give me a solution."

Comment: thanx.i resolved that by adding this to my proguard.txt .    -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.*
-ignorewarnings